Stargazer R: How do I have the variable name in the table?
For instance, if I run:
cars %>% rstatix::get_summary_stats(dist) %>%
  mutate(q1 = unname(q1), q3 = unname(q3)) %>%
  stargazer(summary = FALSE, type = "text")

I get the following output:
======================================================================
  variable n  min max median q1 q3 iqr  mad   mean    sd    se    ci  
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1    1     50  2  120   36   26 56 30  23.722 42.98 25.769 3.644 7.324
----------------------------------------------------------------------

How do I replace variable value which is "1" to "dist"?
